# Template based dynamic div rendering with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code uses a template to display divs based on an array of records. It works fine for the most part. I have added an animation also to display rows. But all the rows are performing the animation together.

How can we modify it to start the second row rendering only after the first one completed with slower animation. Either jQuery or Bootstrap solution will be okay.

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/e0wuchwy/)

**UPDATE**: I also tried "chaining" approach- but that didn't work. [Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/e0wuchwy/2/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <script id="template" type="text/html">
  <div style="border:1px solid silver; float:left; min-height:55px; width:500px;background-color:white;margin:5px 1px 1px 1px; display:none;">
  {CostTypeName}-{Quantity}-{ServicePeriodEndDate}
  </div>
  </script>

  <a id="lnkGetServiceCharges" class="btn icon-btn btn-primary" href="#" style="font-size:20px;">
                    <span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-save img-circle text-primary"></span>
                  Click to Run Demo &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
  </a>

      <div id="divContainer">
      </div>

</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
var result =[{"CostTypeName":" Cost1","Quantity":1.00,"ServicePeriodEndDate":"\/Date(1514678400000)\/"},{"CostTypeName":"Cost2","Quantity":0,"ServicePeriodEndDate":"\/Date(1488499200000)\/"},{"CostTypeName":"Cost3","Quantity":2,"ServicePeriodEndDate":"\/Date(1488499200000)\/"}
]

var template = $('#template').html();

function render(template, data) {
  var patt = /\{([^}]+)\}/g;
  return template.replace(patt, function(_, key) {
    return data[key];
  });
}

  $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#lnkGetServiceCharges").click(function (event) {
                fireDemo();
                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });

function fireDemo()
{
  $.each(result, function(index,item) 
  {        
      //alert(item.CostTypeName);
      var divRef = render(template, item);
      $(divRef).appendTo('#divContainer').show('slow');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following looks working, as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/44ws9wcy/) .

@gaetanoM recommended this approach.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#lnkGetServiceCharges").click(function (event) {
            fireDemo(0);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });

function fireDemo(index)
{
    if (result[index]) {
      var divRef = render(template, result[index]);
      $(divRef).appendTo('#divContainer').show('slow',  
            function() {
            fireDemo(index + 1 );
          });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are firing all the animations in the loop which are going ot all appear to fire at the same instant because the loop is iterating so fast .  you can try a timeout or you can redesign your code so they go one after another:

```
function fireDemo()
{

      //alert(item.CostTypeName);
      var divRef = render(template, item);
      $(result).first().appendTo('#divContainer').show('slow', function showNext() {
            $( this ).next().appendTo('#divContainer').show( "slow", showNext );
      });   

}
```

EDIT:  there is actually an example of your exact scenerio on the jQuery `show()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/) here is there example , I also edited code above

```
$( "#showr" ).click(function() {
  $( "div" ).first().show( "fast", function showNext() {
    $( this ).next( "div" ).show( "fast", showNext );
  });
});
```

Comment: Set timeout didn't change the behavior. Can you please explain how to redesign ? "you can redesign your code so they go one after another" –

Comment: basically instead of your own loop , just use the jQuery selector to get the whole array , then let it iterate through each one using the callback on the `show()` function

Comment: I tired with your updated code - it didn't work as shown this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LijoCheeran/e0wuchwy/1/). Can you update the fiddle if I am missing anything?